# How can I pass a Map object to my script file with EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a Map object I would like to pass to my client-side. I am trying this using EJS through <%- JSON.stringify(...) %> as it has worked for me in the past for arrays. But it doesn't seem to work for Maps. In the script I then tried to console.log(myMap.keys()) and I get this error:

```
TypeError: categories.keys is not a function. (In 'categories.keys()', 'categories.keys' is undefined)
```

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var categories = <%- JSON.stringify(categories) %>;
</script>
```

EDIT:
The problem isn't in the way that variables are loaded. If I try to console.log categories in the console I get this.

```
> console.log(categories)
[Log] {}
```

Basically an empty object.

Comment: Try to console.log in the same script. Maybe console.log is called before JSON string is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Variable 'categories' is undefined before put value in it and haven't 'key' method.

Comment: I don't see how that can help me.